# Custom Attributes Using Linq C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, attributes

So in my Entity class I am using the Description attribute. In the HTML views I can pull the description from the Description attribute for each property which is working correctly.

However the problem I'm facing is that my Entity class looks cluttered with all the Attributes on each property.

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[Description("Enter a name for the input. This is referenced in article 1010")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Description("Enter a description for the input. This is referenced in article 1010")]
public string Description { get; set; }

[Display(Name="Required Dropdown")]
[Description("Select a role for the input. The role is based on your last job.")]
public int RequiredRoleId { get; set; }
```

In this project I make use of FluentValidation. The Validation class is just applied to the top of my Entity class.

```
[Validator(typeof(InputValidation))]
public class Input : IEntityBase { }
```

Inside the `InputValidation` class the Fluent looks like this.

```
public class InputValidation : AbstractValidator<Input>
{
    public InputValidation()
    {
        RuleFor(u => u.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please enter a name").Length(1, 100).WithMessage("Please enter a name that does not exceed 100 characters");
        RuleFor(u => u.Description).Length(1, 500).WithMessage("Please enter a description that does not exceed 500 characters");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to mimic what FluentValidation does here, only for a description attribute. So the custom description attribute would look something like this.

```
public class InputDescription : AbstractDescription<Input>
{
    public InputDescription()
    {
        DescriptionFor(u => u.Name).WithText("Enter a name for the input. This is referenced in article 1010");
        DescriptionFor(u => u.Description).WithText("Enter a description for the input. This is referenced in article 1010");
    }
}
```

Then in my entity class I could removed all the Description attributes for each property and just apply the `InputDescription` class under `[Validator(typeof(InputValidation))]`

Is something like this even possible, if so is it viable?

Comment: Possible? Sure. The intent seems to make sense. Performance wise should be almost the same as accessing the Description attribute, depending on how you process it all. Downside - you might forget to put up a description for a Property, but that can be solved by unit tests, that would check the contents. Is there anything you would need help with?

Comment: I was just thinking for a fail safe if not description is found just output the property name to make sure the application doesn't fall over. I kind of need help with it all. I have the idea in my head but I dont even know where to being.

Comment: True, also if you would like some framework support for your new descriptions, you could use something like https://www.postsharp.net to move your new declarations to the Description attribute of the properties during compile time.

Comment: This looks like a fairly non standard design, and i personally dont think those sorts of attributes should be anywhere near your entities. This is just begging for design problems down the track. However to answer your question everything you describe is possible. You need to research how to use reflection to get attributes from properties. As for the fluent api stuff, its nothing more than returning Interfaces or Concrete classes and/or mixed with extension methods.. Though its kind of a little to broad for one question IMO